# Do multiple spark sessions which query on the same partition in Hadoop table make the query slower?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiple Spark Sessions on different driver node query on the same HDFS file, let's say Table **T1**. Below is the T1 structures.

- Partition by date
- Then partition by first 2 digit of the user id
- User id field
- Other related information of the user.

| partition date | partition first 2 digit | User id | other info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 01 | 01234 | ... |
| 18 | 01 | 01234 | ... |
| 18 | 02 | 02345 | ... |

### Now I tried two scenarios,

1. Create 8 multiple spark sessions on different driver node (using cluster mode) and concurrently query on the exact same partition and user id, every session acquire all the resources as limited in the code, for instance each session takes

   - 1 driver / 1 CPU / 4 GB
   - 4 executors / 1 CPU per executor / 4 GB per executor

And below is the sample query.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE user_id = '01234' AND partition_date IN ('17', '18') AND partition_first_2_digit IN ('01', '02')
```

2. Create only 1 spark session and query using the same above string. This session also acquire all the resources as limited in the code which is equal to multiple sessions case.

   - 1 driver / 1 CPU / 4 GB
   - 4 executors / 1 CPU per executor / 4 GB per executor

And the results surprise me, the query time per application on the multiple spark session case is **10 minutes** which is much higher than one spark session at **5 minutes**!

I am curious about why the multiple spark sessions make the query much slower? Does anyone have the same problems?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: So you have multiple Spark Sessions all reading the same data at the same time?

Comment: Yes, around 8 Spark sessions which  read the same data concurrently at the same time.

Comment: If 8 processes are consuming the same machine resources (RAM, CPU etc) and reading the same file at the same time then you would expect slower runtimes, no?

Comment: The 8 processes are consuming different resources on the same cluster, let's say there are 40 CPUs and 160 GB in the cluster. For multiple spark session case, each process take non-overlap resource for 5 CPUs and 20 GB but they access the same hadoop table with the same partition.

Comment: Unless you have a replication factor of 8 then there's going to be slowdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, in both cases the performance should be same but there are other factors that may be influencing the scheduling of the jobs. From my experience, you could be experiencing any of these constraints.

1. The job pool in which you are firing your spark jobs has less resources than required by 8 instances of your job. Lets say each instance/run require 4 executors so while you are running 8 instances of the job that means you are requesting 32 executors in total. If your job queue is configured to support 20 executors ( executors could be limited by either number of cores or memory allocated to queue or both). your 8 jobs are not able to achieve maximum parallelism and hence appear to be slow as compared to one single instance running at the same time which gets all the resources it needs and is able to achieve maximum parallelism
2. your cluster is running full force and utilising most of it resources for other prod jobs due to which your 8 instances of the same job are waiting for resources at the same time.
3. if you ran a single test for 8 instances, there could be a possibility that there was a write job happening on the parent directory or hive table which could have caused your jobs to enter a wait state.

These are some of the problems which i have seen in my career, there could be other factors as well. i would suggest get access to yarn schedular or queues from your sysadmin and see if one of these is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! I have found the problems. It seems that there are some job writing to the hive table making the rest sessions waiting!